# Not able upload filename into db, in uploading concepts

Tags: cakephp

In my UsersController.php

```
public function uploadFile() 
{
        $filename = '';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {


    $uploadData = $this->data['uploadFile']['image'];
            if ( $uploadData['size'] == 0 || $uploadData['error'] !== 0) {
                return false;
            }

            $filename = basename($uploadData['name']);

            if ($this->User->save($filename)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your imagename has been saved.'));
            }

            $uploadFolder = WWW_ROOT. 'files';
            $filename = time() .'_'. $filename;
            $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $filename;

            if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
                mkdir($uploadFolder);
            }

            if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadData['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
                //$this->set('pdf_path', $fileName);
                return false;
            } 
        }
    }   
}
```

And in my uploadfile.ctp

```
 <?php
  echo $this->Form->create('uploadFile', array( 'type' => 'file'));
  echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file','label' => 'Pdf'));
  echo $this->Form->end('Upload file');
?>
```

In my db I have table name "image" along with some other fields. Now I'm not able to upload file name into db.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table name called 'image', then it should be related to the user model. $this->User->save($filename) needs at least a table field called 'filename' in the User table AND it needs to be assigned to a user via $this->User->id = $user_id;

If your image table has an image model which is related to the user model, read the book's chapter 'Saving related model data' http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto

Comment: we can save filename by doing  $data = array(
                    'User' => array(
                   'file_name' => $filename,
        
                 )
                );
   $this->User->save($data);

Comment: Yeah, you can. But then again: it'll create a new record in the user table (if in the User model no fields are listed as 'required') instead of update because you don't send a related user_id in your save query. How many images per user would you like to have uploaded?